# How to properly label bars on chart in R using Get_Labels?

Tags: r, axis-labels

I have read in Stata data from a survey into R using the haven library. I would like to graph Question Three (Q3) which is a categorical question and sort responses from smallest to largest. Also, I have deleted all the NA responses.

```
DMQ3 <-SurveyData %>% 
  filter(!(Q3 %in% NA)) %>%
  count(Q3) %>%
  mutate(name=reorder(Q3, n)) %>%
  arrange (n)
```

Here is the DMQ3 tibble:

```
> DMQ3
# A tibble: 8 x 2
                            DM3     n
                      <dbl+lbl> <int>
1 6 [100TB &lt; 500TB]              6
2 7 [&gt; 500TB]                    8
3 1 [&lt; 1GB (Gigabyte)]          13
4 8 [Not sure]                     21
5 5 [10TB &lt; 100TB]              23
6 4 [1TB &lt; 10TB]                45
7 2 [1GB &lt; 100GB]               50
8 3 [100GB &lt; 1TB (Terabyte)]    59
```

```
ggplot(DMQ3, aes(x=as.factor(n), y=n)) + 
  geom_col()+
  scale_x_discrete(labels= get_labels(DMQ3$DM3))
```

Here is the resulting bar chart.

[image: Bar chart]

The bars are in the right order but, the labels on the x-axis are not in the correct order. That is "Not Sure" is not the bar at the end but should be the fourth bar from the left. Looking for any help on getting the labels in the proper order. They are ordered properly in the tibble but, not showing up properly in the chart.

```
dput(DMQ3)
structure(list(DM3 = structure(c(6, 7, 1, 8, 5, 4, 2, 3), label = "What is the approximate average volume of data produced per project?", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(`&lt; 1GB (Gigabyte)` = 1, 
`1GB &lt; 100GB` = 2, `100GB &lt; 1TB (Terabyte)` = 3, `1TB &lt; 10TB` = 4, 
`10TB &lt; 100TB` = 5, `100TB &lt; 500TB` = 6, `&gt; 500TB` = 7, 
`Not sure` = 8), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), n = c(6L, 8L, 13L, 21L, 23L, 45L, 50L, 59L), name = structure(1:8, .Label = c("6", 
"7", "1", "8", "5", "4", "2", "3"), scores = structure(c(`1` = 13, 
`2` = 50, `3` = 59, `4` = 45, `5` = 23, `6` = 6, `7` = 8, `8` = 21
), .Dim = 8L, .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8"))), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The fact that these data came from Stata seems irrelevant to your question, so I've deleted the tag as a distraction. The question would be the same for any other history.

Comment: `get_labels()` seems to return the labels in the order of their values (`get_values()`). What is the output of `get_values( DMQ3$DM3, sort.val=F)`? Is it `c(6, 7, 1, 8, 5, 4, 2, 3)`? If so, you should be able to reorder the output of `get_labels(DMQ3$DM3)`, something like `get_labels(DMQ3$DM3)[get_values( DMQ3$DM3, sort.val=F)]`.

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(DMQ3)` if you need more detailed support.

Comment: It didn't work. The output for ```get_values( DMQ3$DM3, sort.val=F)``` is ```1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8```.

Comment: My dput out is listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the labels using `get_labels` function and plot the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sjlabelled)

DMQ3 %>%
  mutate(labels = get_labels(DM3)[as.numeric(DM3)]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=labels, y=n)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]